# How organize TypeScript compilation on big project for development

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, incremental-build

The compile-on-save is [not supported yet by VSCode](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/7015) because some API not implemented on [ts-server](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11229).

We want that feature - fast compile single file on change (fast is less then half-second). We tried `tsc --watch`, and it running over 7 seconds from `.ts` file change to incremental compilation completed.

How to work with TypeScript on big project?

p.s. We do not use webpack.

Comment: which version of TS are you using? I had similar issues when updating TS to latest version. Currently I am using `"typescript": "2.7.2",` it's much faster! They have changed the way they watch files and introduced a bug! If you go to TS github repo you will find issues related with your problem.

Comment: @MarcoTalento I have tried 2.7.2, and all the same - 7 sec... The my version is the latest - 2.9.2.

Comment: Can you share your tsconfig.json? Are you excluding node_modules?

Comment: There [ts.config](https://pastiebin.com/5b3f18269e964). Project contains 842 files and 87k lines of code.